# как можно из строки (с Питон кодом) получить список, заданный константой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите как можно из строки получить список с единственным словарем в нем, к примеру:

```
my_list = list("[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}]")
print(len(my_list))
>>>
38
```

А мне необходимо чтоб длина списка была 1.

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Мне необходимо из строки как в примере получить список внутри которого находится один словарь, если я делаю как показал в вопросе то получается что каждый элемент списка это отдельный символ строки, а мне надо получить список внутри которого будет единственный словарь. Что именно конкретизировать?

Comment: так уберите кавычки - у вас нет никакого словаря  -  а только текстовая строка.  Возможно вам нужна сериализация-десериализация... чтобы в принципе решить все вопросы, но это так - моя догадка. Вряд ли задача сводится к тому чтобы получить "число".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте модуль [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

```
import ast
d=ast.literal_eval("[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}]")
print len(d)  #1
print type(d) #<type 'list'>
print type(d[0]) #<type 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 6):

если я правильно понял задачу, то можно воспользоваться либо [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
In [74]: s
Out[74]: "[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}]"

In [75]: import ast

In [76]: ast.literal_eval(s)
Out[76]: [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}]
```

либо [yaml.safe_load](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):

```
In [78]: import yaml

In [79]: yaml.safe_load(s)
Out[79]: [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}]
```

Comment: А почему бы просто `eval` не использовать ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, `eval` - очень небезопасная "штука"

Comment: Хех, узнаю ipython.